# Using print as a variable name in python

Tags: python

While following a tutorial for python, I got to know that we can use *print* for a variable name, and it works fine. But after assigning the print variable, how do we get back the original print function?

```
>>> print("Hello World!!")
Hello World!!!
>>> print = 5
>>> print("Hi")
```

Now, the last call gives the error **TypeError: 'int' object is not callable**, since now print has the integer value 5.

But, how do we get back the original functionality of print now? Should we use the class name for the print function or something?
As in, `SomeClass.print("Hi")`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
>>> print = 5
>>> print = __builtins__.print
>>> print("hello")
hello
```

Comment: Wow. I was wrong :p. +1 because I never even knew about this

Comment: So here, what exactly is __builtins__?? Is this used for naming builtin functions??

Comment: @stRIker: it is a implementation detail of CPython. You can also use the [`builtins` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html).

Answer (score 7):

You can actually delete the variable so the built-in function will work again:

```
>>> print = 5
>>> print('cabbage')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
>>> del print
>>> print('cabbage')
cabbage
```

Comment: Yeah, I could also have used this.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use as a temp way, do them but after that, apply `print` function to `print` variable:

```
print = __builtins__.print
```